# How to know once user toggle ON/OFF GPS?

Tags: android, geolocation

Please tell a way to know in my app, once user ON/OFF the GPS, so that i can switch the Location provider according to GPS availability.
My app is a service and I am registering both providers in onCreate() method of my Service class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you invoke [`LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(...)`](http://goo.gl/QyZLI) in your  [`LocationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)
you would override `onProviderDisabled` and `onProviderEnabled` and within those two methods you would do whatever you want - switch the provider you are using - in this case.

If you need further explanation, just comment to let me know.

**EDIT:**

> So should i remove the listener like this locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener); in onProviderEnabled() before registering for the listener according to their availabilty?

No. Use 2 conditional `if` statements like so:

```
LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    //request updates for gps provider
}
if (locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
    //request updates for network provider
}
```

This way, if both are on, you will use both, but if only one is on, you will only use that one. If both are off, you of course will use neither.

And you may want to additionally do:

```
 if (!locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && 
        !locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
            //do whatever you want for when both are disabled.
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am registering providers like this locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener); in onCreate() of my service class. And as you said i got LocationListener, So should i remove the listener like this locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener); in onProviderEnabled() before registering for the listener according to their availabilty

Comment: Okay i gave like this locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); and now it look fine.. Now let me test the app and let you know the result

Comment: Awesome. I went outside to test and it is working beautifully. Thanks a lot.